# How to use sudo chown command in python?

Tags: python, passwords, sudo

there are few servers running with python 2.4.3 where pexpect is not working.. Is there any way to place sudo password for sudo chown

Answer (score 1):

Issue resolved. I used ssh - t for remote login to overcome the sudo tty issues and used below one..

import os

os.system(sudo chown xxxx)